# Catch unique index violation and raise_application_error

Tags: exception, oracle11g, unique-constraint, unique-index

Is it possible to catch unique index violation and raise_application_error. We are trying with a blanket trigger and catching the exceptions, however we are always getting oracle exception.

> ORA-00001: unique constraint (TEST_UNIQUE_INDEX) violated

We have a FUNCTION-BASED constraint on the table.

```
CREATE TABLE TEST_CONSTRAINT(
    "ID" NUMBER NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "LOCATION" VARCHAR2(20) NOT NULL, 
    "DEPT" VARCHAR2(20) NOT NULL, 
    "RECORD" NUMBER NOT NULL)
/
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX TEST_UNIQUE_INDEX ON TEST_CONSTRAINT (
    CASE "RECORD" WHEN 1 THEN "LOCATION" ELSE NULL END, 
    CASE "RECORD" WHEN 1 THEN "DEPT"     ELSE NULL END)
/
```

before update trigger code

```
EXCEPTION 
  WHEN DUP_VAL_ON_INDEX THEN
      ERROR_MESSAGE := SQLERRM;
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('SQLERRM '|| ERROR_MESSAGE);
  WHEN OTHERS THEN
      ERROR_MESSAGE := SQLERRM;
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('SQLERRM '|| ERROR_MESSAGE);     
END;
```

[test schema here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/3a537/3)

Edit 1:

The requirement here is to impose selective uniqueness i.e. only one set of location/dept can be set as a record (being a boolean in app). In all other cases, we have to generate a raise_application_error.

Answer (score 0):

The trigger would be executed BEFORE the update happens. Since there would be no exception during its execution (all it does is print the system date), no exception would be raised. Then, the update is actually executed, and that's when you get the error message from the database.

To catch the exception that occurs because of the UPDATE statement, the UPDATE statement itself must be enclosed within a PL/SQL block, as below.

```
DECLARE 
  V_DATE DATE;
  ERROR_MESSAGE VARCHAR2(1000); 
BEGIN
  SELECT SYSDATE INTO V_DATE FROM DUAL;
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('SYSDATE '|| V_DATE);

  UPDATE TEST_CONSTRAINT SET RECORD = 1 WHERE ID = 3;

EXCEPTION 
  WHEN DUP_VAL_ON_INDEX THEN
      ERROR_MESSAGE := SQLERRM;
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Error occurred. SQLERRM '|| ERROR_MESSAGE);
  WHEN OTHERS THEN
      ERROR_MESSAGE := SQLERRM;
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('SQLERRM '|| ERROR_MESSAGE);     
END;
/
```

**Reference**:

[Handling PL/SQL Errors on Oracle® Database PL/SQL Language Reference](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28370/errors.htm#LNPLS007)

Comment: I can't have a pl/sql block as these updates are triggered from app api. Hence we need to catch those and display appropriate error message.

Comment: If it is possible to create a procedure with the UPDATE statement in the database, then you can call the procedure to execute the UPDATE. Alternatively, you can consider first checking from the app api itself if the new values would result in "duplicate" rows. If they would, then you can choose not to execute the UPDATE.